# How to use reflection to access details of member variables defined as an abstract type

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class which is of the following form:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public static AbstractClass<Boolean> variable1 = AbstractClass.create("key", value);
}
```

The `AbstractClass` looks something like this:

```
public abstract AbstractClass<T> {
  private String key;
  private T value;
  protected AbstractClass(String key, T value) {
     this.key = key;
     this.value = value;
  }

  protected abstract void func();

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public T get() {
    return value;
  }


  public static create(String key, String default) {
    return new AbstractClass<String>(key, default) {
      @Override
      protected void func() {
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I want to write a test on `SomeClass`, which access all such variables[1...] and perform a test on their "key". How can I do this ?

Here's my try on this:

```
for (Field field : allFields) {
  Class<?> targetType = field.getType();
  AbstractClass<?> flag = (AbstractClass<?>) field.get(targetType.newInstance());
  assertTrue(flag.getKey().startsWith("xyz"));
```

Clearly, using `newInstance` can't work as `targetType` here is abstract, and throws `InstantiationException`.

The other way is to just access all the variables variable1, variable2, etc statically, retrieve the key from them, and perform assertions on it. However, clearly, that would mean that if someone adds a new field in the in `SomeClass`, someone has to manually modify the test file and write assertions. This doesn't really help, because people might forget to write tests.

So I think using reflection might solve that. However, I think this is impossible using reflection, so wondering if there's any way to get around this ?
Alternatively, any other to automate the tests so that tests get all the fields added and developer doesn't need to worry about it ?

Comment: Can you share any implementation details of `AbstractClass`? Also, can you show me how you're getting `allFields` in your `for` block? It's not clear to me if you're trying to make assertions about an instance of AbstractClass or `AbstractClass.class` itself.

Comment: This is how I am accessing allFields.
`allFields = SomeClass.class.getFields();`

Basically, `AbstractClass` contains a key and a value. I have to retrieve the key and make some assertions on the key.

Comment: Your title is meaningless. There is no such thing as an abstract field in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The fields you are iterating are `SomeClass`' ones isn't it?

If so the argument you have to pass to get its value is the intance of `SomeClass` or anything if the field is static, which is actually the case in your example.

```
 AbstractClass<?> flag = (AbstractClass<?>) field.get(null);
```

Note that it might be better to split it in two steps to check if what `field.get` returns is an intance of `AbstractClass`